# Cannot load .rda

Tags: r, dataframe, save, load

I'm having trouble loading a data frame in R.

```
var1 = c('blue','red','green')
var2 = c(101,102,103)
df = data.frame(var1,var2)
print(df)

   var1  var2
1  blue   101
2  red    102
3  green  103

save(df, file = "mydata.rda")
```

when I try to load `mydata` with `load()` it returns the name of the dataframe ("df") instead of the actual data. I don't think there's a problem with the .rda file because I can manually load it in using R's point-and-click functions (i.e. File > Open File), but I can't load it in-line:

```
a = load("mydata.rda")
a
[1] "df"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`load()` does not return the object. It produces a *side effect* where the objects saved in the file are loaded into the environment. Type `df` and you'll have your data. Use `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` for the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks so much!

Comment: One reason why I tend to use `readRDS` whenever native-R object storage is needed. (Might be ... okay, definitely related: `quantmod::getSymbols` default of `auto.assign=TRUE` drives me batty.) So many times I have had an unintended side-effect in a function, and it has taken me *hours* to figure out why things kept shifting on me.